# Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n}$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \: \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n=\frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{x}{x-1} \: when \: |x|>1 
$$

It is convergent.

The above is the textbook's solution...

Here's my work :

$$
lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0 \:\:when\;x\geq1
$$
 $$It's\;\; divergent \;\;by\;\;the\;\;n^{th} test$$
Where's my mistake ?

Comment: What is the $n$-th test?

Comment: If the limit to infinity of the series is 0, then the divergence test is inconclusive... it is not divergent if the limit is 0

Comment: nth test is taking the limits of term when n approaches to infinity

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you think the $n^{\text{th}}$ test is, but taking the limit of the terms should yield only two conclusions

- If the limit is **not** $0$, then the series is *divergent*.
- If the limit is $0$, the test is *inconclusive* (we know nothing about the series' behavior). Another test is needed.